# Take user input from Python to SQL query

Tags: python, sql

I am creating a store front page where the user will be able to search for items inside of an SQL data base. I am having issues with the python logic where I am trying to use the WHERE logic to find what the user hass entered. Here is my code:

```
username = input("Enter your username >>> ")
password = input("Enter your password >>> ")

try:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY email')
except:
    print("The database does not exist")
else:
    list_of_users = cursor.fetchall()


def login(email: str, pwd: str, list_of_users: [()]) -> bool:
    for db_email, db_pwd in list_of_users:
        if (email == db_email) and (pwd == db_pwd):
            return True
    return False

#----------Storefront----------#
while login(username, password, list_of_users) == True:
    search_bar = input("Enter what item you would like to look up >>> ")
    sql = "SELECT * FROM item_in_stock WHERE item_name = "
    cursor.execute(sql , search_bar)
    for row in iter(cursor.fetchone, None):
        print(row)
```

also if someone has a better way of testing to see if what I get out of the table is the correct value that I am looking for instead of using

```
for row in iter(cursor.fetchone, None):
    print(row)
```

then please do share as I do not understand what that for loop is doing.

When I run the program, this is what I get:

```
Enter your username >>> joe@gmail.com
Enter your password >>> qwerty
Enter what item you would like to look up >>> Jumper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jerem/PycharmProjects/assignment_core/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql , search_bar)
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

No clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cursor.execute as you are using it accepts two parameters, sql and parameters. I believe, according to [sqlite docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) and [sqlite parameter reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders), that you should define your string sql with `sql = "SELECT * FROM item_in_stock WHERE item_name = ?"` and pass parameters into cursor.execute in a tuple.

All in all, you might want to try something along the lines of:

```py
while login(username, password, list_of_users) == True:
    search_bar = input("Enter what item you would like to look up >>> ")
    sql = "SELECT * FROM item_in_stock WHERE item_name = ?"
    cursor.execute(sql, (search_bar))
    for row in iter(cursor.fetchone, None):
        print(row)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives this error message. I see what the question mark does, but I cannot give it an exact number of question marks as I need it to be able to search for a variety of items. 
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied.
What I entered was Jumper, which has 6 characters, and it is set to accept 1 character as there is only 1 question mark

Comment: Oops, I forgot that because you are passing a tuple with only one element, Python doesn't see it as a tuple. It is trying to pass each character of search bar into the query. To explicitly show that it is a tuple with one value, try `cursor.execute(sql, (search_bar,))` (note the comma after search bar).